# TypeError: async is not a function

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm doing a slash command handler using discord.js, and I'm getting the "not a function" error.
I saw other questions here and some videos on YouTube but I still couldn't solve the problem

This is the code

```
client.on('interactionCreate', async (interaction => {
    if (!interaction.isCommand()) return

    const command = client.commands.get(interaction.commandName)

    if (!command) return
}))
```

And this is the error

```
client.on('interactionCreate', async (interaction => {
                               ^

TypeError: async is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\...\Desktop\...\...\...\index.js:60:32)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1103:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1155:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47
```

I have tried:
`npm i async`
and `var async = require('async')`

Before I created the variable the error was that async was not defined but now it shows this new error

Comment: You have your closing parenthesis in the wrong place. You did `async (interaction => {})`, it needs to be `async (interaction) => {}`

Comment: Or, since there is exactly one parameter: `async interaction => {}`

Answer (score 2):

You misplaced a ")"

```
client.on("interactionCreate", async (interaction) => {
  if (!interaction.isCommand()) return;

  const command = client.commands.get(interaction.commandName);

  if (!command) return;
});
```

Comment: Not quite "missing." It was "misplaced" at the end of the function.

Answer (score 2):

You are calling `client.on('interactionCreate', f )` where `f` is represented as:

```js
async (interaction => {
    if (!interaction.isCommand()) return

    const command = client.commands.get(interaction.commandName)

    if (!command) return
})
```

JavaScript is interpreting this as `async( ... )`.

You can either remove the parentheses surrounding your function, or move the closing parentheses to the end of the arguments of your arrow function.

```js
client.on('interactionCreate', async interaction => {
    if (!interaction.isCommand()) return

    const command = client.commands.get(interaction.commandName)

    if (!command) return
})
```

OR

```js
client.on('interactionCreate', async (interaction) => {
    if (!interaction.isCommand()) return

    const command = client.commands.get(interaction.commandName)

    if (!command) return
})
```